# Thread.sleep or yield when polling in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, polling

I'm implementing a blocking file lock in Java, and when trying to acquire a lock I have a code block something like this:

```
while(!fileLockIsAcquired())
{
    Thread.sleep(100); //is this cool?
    tryAcquireFileLock();
}
```

That value of 100 milliseconds seems overly rigid to me, and I wonder if the scheduler couldn't be more intelligent if I used `Thread.sleep(0)` or `Thread.yield()`. Yield seems to me to communicate intent better, but I'm not sure that I fully understand how it is interpreted by the JVM. Is one option clearly better than the other?

The file is a remote file accessed through a webservice which has no blocking lock method, so I have to implement the blocking myself.

Comment: Why not just block? You're not accomplishing anything useful by spin-locking.

Comment: `yield` has no useful semantics; it had a point in the days before Java 1.3, when on some platforms the JVM still used green threads.

Comment: @EJP this is actually a cross-process file lock. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Uh, file locking is advisory only. What kind of lock do you want exactly? Note that prior to 1.7, Java could not `open(O_CREAT | O_EXCL)`. Do you want to create sentinels or map part of files?

Comment: What technique are you using? `FileChannel` has a blocking, interruptible `lock` method.

Comment: @MikeFHay That doesn't answer my question. You aren't doing anything in the loop except spin and yield/sleep/wait. Why not block?

Comment: @EJP then I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "block"?

Comment: The file is a remote file accessed through a webservice which has no blocking lock method, so I have to implement the blocking myself.

Comment: So you're polling it. Using `yield` will make your polling rate much higher, which is probably not what you'd want. BTW you could make your webservice block, i.e. postpone its response until the lock is free, subject to a timeout.

Comment: Excellent point @Marko, I hadn't considered that, and now that you've mentioned it I think `sleep(100)` is about right as a simple solution. I don't know if you want to turn your comment into an answer which I can accept, but I'm happy that my question has been sufficiently answered.

Comment: Turned into an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using yield will make your polling rate much higher, which is probably not what you'd want. This is why I consider your current code as an acceptable first solution.

On the other hand, you could make your Web service block (postpone its response until the lock is acquired) subject to a timeout. This would be a more solid solution since you could have both quick reaction once the lock is acquired, and a modest polling rate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe wait is a better choice than anything else, the reason being because other thread can notify when it releases the lock. Advantage with wait is that it will immediately come out once notified but sleep will not.

Comment: Good answer, but in my case this is actually a file lock which can be acquired by a different process. I'll edit the question to clarify.